# How can I preserve URL anchor when using match-redirect in rails 3 routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have created a route like this:

```
    match "/help" => redirect("/faq"), :as => stackoverflow_help
```

I am trying to add an anchor tag to the url to go to a particular section in the faq page. For e.g.

```
    link_to "Faq", stackoverflow_help_path(:anchor =>"etiquette")
```

is just getting redirected to "http://stackoverflow.com/faq"  but loosing the "etiquette" anchor. How can I make it go to "http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette"?

Comment: Was this issue resolved?

Comment: I am using my previous format:
stackoverflow_help_path(:anchor =>"etiquette"). Interestingly, this is browser specific. It works in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Safari.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to do is add #etiquette to the end of the url, you could do this:

```
link_to "Faq", stackoverflow_help_path + "#etiquette"
```

All thats doing is appending the anchor to the end, but that should be just fine for what you're trying to do.